# Finding overlap of given list

Tags: python-3.x

Find overlap which given list, a list of intervals like [2, 4], returns whether any two intervals overlap. Boundary overlaps don't count.
Example:

```
`>>> check_overlap(li=[[1,5], [8,9], [3,6]]) 
 True 
 >>> check_overlap(li=[[1,5], [5,6]]) 
 False`

data= [[1, 5], [8, 9], [3, 6]]
values = [[value for value in range(elem[0], elem[1])]for elem in data]
print(values)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8], [3, 4, 5]]
```

After that i want to know how to check with each element in a list whether any two intervals overlapping.

Comment: Are these intervals always bound by integer values?

Comment: @Mortz Yes, all the intervals are integer only.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it, and where exactly do you get stuck with your attempts?

Comment: @Energya, i tried like,extracted values for given range in list. [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 3, 4, 5]. Then checked if len(values) != len(list(set(values))): returning true .If one element overlapping this approach working perfectly. For two elements i got stuck. Now i figured out adding another condition like ,if len(values) - len(list(set(values))) >= 2: return true .

Comment: @user5442468 can you add that into your question? That way, people trying to answer you can give better suggestions for what you are trying, or explain why your approach hasn't worked so far :)

Answer (score 0):

For checking the overlap, I would sort the bigger list with first element of the sublists, and check the 2nd element of a sublist is bigger than the 1st element of the next sublist.

```
def overlap(li):
    li.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    for i in range(len(li)-1):
        if li[i][1] > li[i+1][0]:
            return True

    return False

print(overlap([[1,5], [8,9], [3,6]]))
print(overlap([[1,5], [5,6]]))
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have integers you can indeed use range to do this test:

```py
def check_overlap(li):
  ranges = [range(r[0]+1, r[1]-1) for r in li]
  return any(any(e-1 in r for r in ranges) for l in li for e in l)
```

On the other hand, if you have floating point values you'll have to tests both bounds of the interval individually (using `<` and `>`):

```py
def is_in_range(value, boundaries):
  m, M = boundaries
  return value > m+1 and value < M-1

def check_overlap(li):
  return any(any(is_in_range(e, r) for r in li) for l in li for e in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function as such:

```
from itertools import combinations

def check_overlap(li):
    lists = [list(range(a, b)) for a, b in li]  # Shorter way of your values = ... line
    for l1, l2 in combinations(lists, 2): 
        if any(l in l2 for l in l1): 
            return True
    return False
```

The `combinations(lists, 2)` call gives you all possible unique combinations of different elements.

Next, the `any()` function takes any iterable and returns `True` if any of the elements in the iterable are `True` (or rather 'truthy'). In this case, the `l in l2 for l in l1` is a generator expression, but would work the same with square brackets around it to explicitly make it into a list first.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sets and check for intersection -

```
data= [[1, 5], [8, 9], [3, 6]]
sets_from_data = [set(range(*l)) for l in data]
intersection_exists = bool(max([len(a.intersection(b)) for a in sets_from_data for b in sets_from_data if a != b]) > 0)
intersection_exists
# True
```